# Is there any way to share Y axis among only part of subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have N subplots, and I want to share Y axis for all but one of them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can specify which suplots shares which axis with which axes (this is not a typo I mean this sentence). There's a `sharex` and a `sharey` argument for `add_subplot`:

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y1 = np.arange(5)
y2 = y1 * 2
y3 = y1 * 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)                # independant y axis (for now)
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132, sharey=ax1)    # share y axis with first plot
ax2.plot(x, y2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)                # independant y axis
ax3.plot(x, y3)
plt.show()
```

this will create a plot like this (1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> share the y axis, but the 3<sup>rd</sup> does not):

[image: Three plots, the left and middle one share a common y axis. The right plot has an independant y scale.]

You can find another example of this in the matplotlib examples ["Shared axis Demo"](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html).

Answer (score 3):

if you are using this format.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4,1,sharex=True,figsize=(8,8))
```

You can try

```
axs[2].sharey(axs[1])

axs[3].sharey(axs[1])
```

After each subplot.